# Trying to understand formula $T(N) = |Ops| \times \frac{Time}{Op} $ for the time an algorithm takes

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-mathematics

I am not sure how to interpret the formula given in my professor's slides.

> We assume (for simplicity) that each operation ***takes the same amount of time*** to complete.
>
> Time an algorithm takes on input size $N$ is then given as $T(N)$:
>
> $$T(N) = |Ops| \times \frac{Time}{Op} $$

I am horrible at math notation, and I don't understand what the equation represents. I recognize the operation symbols, but I'm not sure what the variables like $Ops$ are supposed to represent. I assume both $Ops$ and $Op$ have something to do with operations, but I don't know what. I assume $Ops$ refers to the total amount of operations, but why would it need to be an absolute value? How can I do less than zero operations?

My question is, *what does this formula represent?*

**Here is the full slide:**
[image]

Comment: $Ops$ is the "set" of operations. $|Ops|$ is the cardinality of this "set", i.e. the number of operations. $Op$ is the time of execution of a specific operation. $Time$ is the total time of execution for all operations.

Comment: @enedil Thanks!

Comment: This equation makes little sense as written. I'm pretty sure enedil is incorrect about $Time$ and $Op$, and the intent was $\frac{Time}{Op}$ was supposed to mean "time per operation". The whole slide could be improved by just saying that we're just counting "operations" and not worrying about time. At that point, the "equation" becomes just $T(N)=|Ops|$. What the instructor is trying to say but making falsely and needlessly "formal" is just that $T(N)$ is the number of operations an algorithm takes on input of size $N$. They should have just written this natural language sentence.